# converting string dateTime yyyy-dd-mm to January 01, 2023

Tags: flutter, dart, date, datetime

I want to display the string of datetime `2023-01-01 11:59:59:0000` in a readable manner like `January 01, 2023 11:59:59 AM`

I do have a controllers for both `DateFrom` to `DateTo` and this accepts DateTime values. So once the controllers have the value I want them to be displayed `January 01,2023 11:59:59AM` instead of the raw DateTime format.

I have this error `Trying to read MMMM from  at 0`

This is my first attempt on converting the display of the value

```
 textContainer("Date From: ",
              "${(DateFormat('MMMM d, y', 'en_US').parse(_couponDateFromCtrlr.text))}"),
 textContainer("Date From: ",
              "${(DateFormat('MMMM d, y', 'en_US').parse(_couponDateFromCtrlr.text))}")
```

and this is my second attempt and it gives me `invalid date format` error

```
_couponDateFromCtrlr.text != null
              ? textContainer("Date From: ",
                  "${(DateFormat('MMMM d, y', 'en_US').parse(_couponDateFromCtrlr.text))}")
              : const Text("No Date From Selected"),
          _couponDateToCtrlr.text != null
              ? textContainer("Date To: ",
                  "${(DateFormat('MMMM d, y', 'en_US').parse(_couponDateToCtrlr.text))}")
              : const Text("No Date To Selected")
```

and this is the ui of it when displaying.

[image: Here is the Date Time I wanna change and I want to change it to April 26, 2023 3:58PM]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to get `DateTime` from the string format of `2023-01-01 11:59:59:0000` and then parse it to the string in this format `January 01,2023 11:59:59AM`:

```
final date = DateFormat('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss', 'en_US')
            .parse("2023-01-01 11:59:59:0000"); // string from your text controller
final string = DateFormat('MMMM d, y hh:mm:ss a', 'en_US').format(date); // result --> January 01,2023 11:59:59AM
```

If you get `DateTime` format from your `_couponDateFromCtrlr` you can skip the first part.

Comment: Thank you, the general logic is here and it helped me solved the problem for previewing the date and time.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the `DateTime` value to the following function:

`DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(value)`

This should return you the required format.
Refer the cheatsheet available here for your date format needs.

[DateFormat Flutter: 2 Ways to Master DateTime Format](https://www.flutterbeads.com/format-datetime-in-flutter/)

Happy coding :)

Comment: Hello, thank you for the resource will definitely use this one!